# Select All shortcut key Command+A no longer works

Tags: keyboard

This morning, I found out that the Command+A shortcut key for selecting all failed to work. I have gone into the keyboard shortcuts preference and did not find anything useful. Is there any suggestion on what to do to fix or at least troubleshoot my problem? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Does this happen in all applications? It's really odd that a single shortcut key should stop working, while others continue to work.

Comment: Yes, it failed for all applications.

Comment: are you sure the command-key is working? ie; other shortcuts work fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reboot in Safe Mode and see if it works.

[Here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1564) and [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1455) are some Apple support documents on Safe Boot Mode.

Comment: This seems to fix it, after safe boot, I can perform a regular boot and the problem goes away. I think the problem is with some app which hijacks the shortcut key, but I don't know which one. I have to keep an eye when launching new apps. Thank you.

Comment: @Hai Yes, definitely keep on eye on your new applications. I've had that happen more than once. :-)